# how to find all occurrences of a word using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

how can I find  all occurrences of the  word `"good "` in the the following string using regex

```
f = "good and obj is a  \good to look for it is good"
```

Comment: must the 2nd escaped "good" be part of the result?

Comment: I count three words `good` in there. So the question is, what is your definition of a word?

Comment: yes how could I find them in f ?

Comment: What do you mean *"find"*? Do you just want to know if it's there? How many times it appears? At which indices it starts? What are your rules for determining which appearances should count - do all of them count? Only if followed by a space? Above all, **what have you tried so far, and what exactly is the problem with it?**

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = re.compile("good")
regex.findall("good and obj is a \good to look for it is good")

['good', 'good', 'good']
```

Comment: sorry, I think I edited your answer instead of mine, by mistake. Anyway, the question asks for good with a space after

Answer (score 0):

```
f = r"good and obj is a  \good to look for it is good"
m = re.findall('good ', f)
```

will give you:

```
['good ', 'good ']
```

You should use a raw string when defining f, unless the `\` is supposed to go with `g`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find all the 'good'

```
re.findll('good', f)
```

will work. 
else
you can try this

```
import re
s = "good and obj is a \good to look for it is good"
s = re.sub(r'[^\/\s]good', '', s)
print re.findall(r'good', s)
```